# Need help creating a custom aux file read/write routine to suit my needs

Tags: cross-referencing, external-files, input, auxiliary-files, output

I require two new commands, `\createreference` and `\citereference`, to work with. They should work as shown in the following examples:

`\createreference{john}{John Q. Citizen}` should write the text “John Q. Citizen” into the file `myreferences.aux`. The text should be somehow associated with the corresponding entry `john`.

`\citereference{john}` should print out “??” if no `john` entry can be found in `myreferences.aux` (or if the file doesn’t exist). However, it should print out the corresponding text (in this case “John Q. Citizen”) if the entry is found.

This should work even if `\createreference` appears after `\citereference` in the code.

I don’t have enough low-level expertise to be able to do this. Does someone else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I did not understand where do you want to put the text:  in the main file `jobname.aux` or in the separate file.  If the former, this works (basically modelled after the standard `\ref-\label` mechanism):

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% The command reference writes \newreference into the aux file
\def\createreference#1#2{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@mainaux{}%
         {\string\newreference{#1}{#2}}%
  \@esphack}
% The command \newreference defines new command named after the first
% argument that produces the second one
\def\newreference#1#2{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname rfr@#1\endcsname{#2}}
% And using the reference
\def\citereference#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname rfr@#1\endcsname\relax??\else
  \csname rfr@#1\endcsname\fi}
% LaTeX checks at the end of document whether references have 
% been changed.  If any reference is changed, 
% \tempswa is set to true.  Here we add \newreference commands
% to the list to be checked.
\AtEndDocument{\def\newreference#1#2{%
    \edef\reserved@a{#2}%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname rfr@#1\endcsname\reserved@a\else
    \@tempswatrue\fi}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\createreference{john}{John Q. Citizen}
\citereference{john} and \citereference{george}
\end{document}
```

**Update** Added checking whether the references have been changed.

**Update 2** Changed `\def` to `\edef` to handle accents

Comment: Sweet, this is exactly what I want and it works. Is there any chance you could add into this the feature that puts out a compilation warning "things may have changed. please recompile" if required? I hope it's not too much of a hassle to add.

Comment: Ok, see update.

Comment: @Boris: The \createreference command does not seem be entirely compatible with non-latin characters, e.g. \createreference{john}{John Q. Staatsbürger}. No errors, but I do get the following: _LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right._ The source of this is the use of the character ü (or \"u). Do you know what could be the problem? I’m using both \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} and \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}. (The references come out correctly, though.)

Comment: @TheStochasticLiberal Try changing `\def\reserved@a{#2}%` to `\edef\reserved@a{#2}%` as in the update

Answer (score 8):

You can use (or rather abuse?) the standard mechanism:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\createreference}[2]{%
  \def\@currentlabel{\unexpanded{#2}}\label{#1}}
\newcommand{\citereference}[1]{\ref{#1}}
\makeatother
```

but I have some doubts whether this is the right thing to do. If you load also `hyperref` it's probably better to use `\ref*` instead of `\ref`, so that no link is created.

Since this uses the standard mechanism, when a new reference is created, the message `Label(s) may have changed` will be issued.

The `.aux` file's job is to record information that may change from one run to the other. Declaring a fixed association between `john` and `John Q. Citizen` is better done in the preamble, so that all such associations are easily under control:

```
%%% in the preamble
\newcommand{\createassociation}[2]{%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname association@#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand{\citeassociation}[1]{\csname association@#1\endcsname}
\createassociation{john}{John Q. Citizen}

%%% in the document

This is the name: \citeassociation{john}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref) provides this functionality by default. Here's a minimal example that fulfils your request ([`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) only provides dummy text, *Lorem Ipsum* style):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{zref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/zref

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\createreference}[2]{%
  \def\@reftext{#2}% Store contents of reference (#2)
  \zref@labelbylist{#1}{special}% Special label writes to .aux
}
\newcommand{\citereference}[1]{%
  \zref@extractdefault{#1}{reftext}{\textbf{??}}% Extract reference, or print ??
}
\zref@newlist{special}% Create a new reference list called special
\zref@newprop{reftext}{\@reftext}% Create property reftext that holds \@reftext
\zref@addprop{special}{reftext}% Special reference list holds reftext
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\createreference{john}{John~Q.\ Citizen}
Do you know \citereference{john} or \citereference{susan}?

\lipsum[7]

\createreference{susan}{\textbf{Suzie}~$\textrm{Q}^2$}
Yes, I know \citereference{john} and \citereference{susan}.

\end{document}
```

You'll note that formatting is preserved within the referenced text. Here's part of the `\jobname.aux` file containing the `zref` labels, showing how the information and formatting is stored:

```
\zref@newlabel{john}{\reftext{John\nobreakspace  {}Q.\ Citizen}}
\zref@newlabel{susan}{\reftext{\textbf  {Suzie}\nobreakspace  {}$\textrm  {Q}^2$}}
```