# highlight line numbers in listings

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, highlighting, line-numbering

I would like to highlight the line numbers of the lines I refer to with `lstlistings`.
I use escape characters to define labels in my Listing to which I refer later in my document (e.g. see Line X of Listing Y).

How can I make the line number of line X of Listing Y colorful?

The image below shows how it should look like. This was created by comparing the line number to a certain value. I would like to compare the line number to the value of a reference.

[image: This is what it should look like]

Here is a MWE in which I compare the line number against a hardcoded 5. My question is now, how to highlight the line number of the line in which I defined the label `code:label`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\usepackage{listings}

% define C++ style
\lstdefinestyle{cppStyle}
{
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,
  tabsize=2,
  captionpos=b,
  frame=lines,
  breaklines=true,
  % language related
  language=C++,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  % numbering
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
    style=cppStyle,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
    caption={Manual Definition -- \emph{Oh, what a mess!}},
    label=lst:notNumbered,
    numberstyle={\ifnum\value{lstnumber}=5\color{green}\fi}
] 
/* #include "readTwoPhaseEulerFoamControls.H" */
#include "readTwoPhaseLESEulerFoamControls.H"

// Solve the Momentum equation (*@\label{code:label}@*)

tmp<fvVectorMatrix> UEqn 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please unaccept my answer and accept phfaist's instead? I unwittingly overcomplicated the matter by reimplementing what was already provided by the `listings` package!

Comment: @John thanks nonetheless for your well done answer.

Comment: This question explaines how to highlight more than one line [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191771/highlight-line-numbers-in-listings-conflict-with-hyperref-package].

Comment: Highlighting line numbers introduces a package conflict with `hyperref`.

Comment: Conflict solved: [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191771/highlight-line-numbers-in-listings-conflict-with-hyperref-package%5D]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@John's answer should work well and is very well explained; for completeness here's an alternative solution.

For me, it works to simply replace the line

```
numberstyle={\ifnum\value{lstnumber}=5\color{green}\fi}
```

by

```
numberstyle={\ifthenelse{\equal{\ref{code:label}}{\value{lstnumber}}}{\color{green}}{}}
```

using `\ifthenelse` from the `ifthen` package (of course don't forget the corresponding `\usepackage{ifthen}`).

Comment: Pah! You're absolutely right `:-)`. I hadn't realised that `\label` works properly inside listings; that is, I hadn't realised that `\label` would grab the current line number.

Comment: What if I wanted to place several labels (e.g. 2 labels) within the Listing and highlight all the lines in which a label was placed? I seem to be unable to come up with a working nested condition.

Comment: @DohnJoe Sorry I didn't have time to answer, but I see now others have already done so and have provided a better solution :)

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit tricky because the line number to be highlighted is not defined until later on in the file. However, you can use an idea previously expounded by egreg (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49032/25356) and piggyback on LaTeX's existing labelling mechanism, which writes information to the `.aux` file in order to be persistent between compilation runs.

### Explanation

The following `\labelline` command associates the given label with the number of the current line (which is given by `\thelstnumber`).

```
\newcommand\labelline[1]{%
  \def\@currentlabel{\thelstnumber}\label{#1}}
```

The following `\lineref` command extracts the value from the given label, returning `0` if the label is not yet defined. (The label `foo` is internally stored as the command `\r@foo`, hence the check of whether `r@#1` is defined.)

```
\newcommand\lineref[1]{
  \@ifundefined{r@#1}{0}{\ref{#1}}
}
```

Note that you'll need two passes of the compiler in order to resolve the labels. Happily, having used the existing labelling infrastructure, the compiler will give you the standard hint about "run LaTeX again to get references right".

### Output

[image]

### Complete code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\usepackage{listings}

% define C++ style
\lstdefinestyle{cppStyle}
{
  basicstyle=\footnotesize,
  tabsize=2,
  captionpos=b,
  frame=lines,
  breaklines=true,
  % language related
  language=C++,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  % numbering
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\tiny
}



\makeatletter
\newcommand\labelline[1]{%
  \def\@currentlabel{\thelstnumber}\label{#1}}
\newcommand\lineref[1]{
  \@ifundefined{r@#1}{0}{\ref{#1}}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[
    style=cppStyle,
    escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
    caption={Manual Definition -- \emph{Oh, what a mess!}},
    label=lst:notNumbered,
    numberstyle={\ifnum\value{lstnumber}=\lineref{code:label}\color{green}\fi}
] 
/* #include "readTwoPhaseEulerFoamControls.H" */
#include "readTwoPhaseLESEulerFoamControls.H"

// Solve the Momentum equation (*@ \labelline{code:label} @*)

tmp<fvVectorMatrix> UEqn 
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```