# Pattern to detect need for recompilation from auxfile

Tags: compiling, warnings, auxiliary-files, write

I am using an auxfile to access the results of some computations which I need before they can actually be computed. Since this requires two runs when something changes the result I would like to have a mechanism to detect such changes and print a message to the user.

I vaguley remember a pattern where a hook was installed to compare the value to be written with the previous value (non immediate write hook), and then setting a flag based on which a warning is displayed to the user, informing him that recompilation is necessary.

<strike>Unfortunatly I can not find the example again. Does anybody know this pattern and can point me to some (preferably *simple*) example code?</strike>

Despearte googling turned up the example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49035/19326 However I have an issue understanding it ([Purpose of AtEndDocument{\def}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213788/19326)).

Since this question is currently in a bad spot (not a real question anymore I guess, I wonder whats the best way to carry on, see my comment below)

Comment: Since I found the example I am not sure how to handle this best, delete the question, paste the awnser from the other question, or add a MWE with explanations. I would prefer the last option, however I will have to understand `AtEndDocument(\def ... )` first.

Answer (score 4):

`\usepackage[aux]{rerunfilecheck}` issues a warning if the auxfile has changed and asks for another run.

Comment: +1: While this package seems to provide a solution, I am interested in the pattern I described above, rather than how to use a package that does this based on checksums. While the solution might be the best/easiest to use, I am also interested in an alternative for integration in my package without a dependency and for learning purposes.

Comment: Some explanations about the benefits of `rerunfilecheck` can be found here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213789/19326

Answer (score 0):

The code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49035/19326, which is pasted here for reference poses as an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% The command reference writes \newreference into the aux file
\def\createreference#1#2{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@mainaux{}%
         {\string\newreference{#1}{#2}}%
  \@esphack}
% The command \newreference defines new command named after the first
% argument that produces the second one
\def\newreference#1#2{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname rfr@#1\endcsname{#2}}
% And using the reference
\def\citereference#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname rfr@#1\endcsname\relax??\else
  \csname rfr@#1\endcsname\fi}
% LaTeX checks at the end of document whether references have 
% been changed.  If any reference is changed, 
% \tempswa is set to true.  Here we add \newreference commands
% to the list to be checked.
\AtEndDocument{\def\newreference#1#2{%
    \edef\reserved@a{#2}%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname rfr@#1\endcsname\reserved@a\else
    \@tempswatrue\fi}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\createreference{john}{John Q. Citizen}
\citereference{john} and \citereference{george}
\end{document}
```

We notice the following pattern:

1. Create your own def macro `yourDefMacro` to assign values to a given key
2. Whenever you want to store something in the auxfile write the string`\yourDefMacro{key}{value}` to the auxfile
3. At the end of the document redefine the def macro to a checker macro that compares the current value of the macro `key` to the value that will be assigned to it.

Here are the corresponding codeparts:

### 1. Def Macro

```
\def\newreference#1#2{%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname rfr@#1\endcsname{#2}}
```

Note that this macro actually adds the prefix `rfr@` to the actual name being defined. The add is usually not recognized as a character in document, avoiding namespace clutter (This is changed for the definition of the macros by wrapping it in `\makeatletter` `\makeatother`).

### 2. Writing to auxfile

```
\def\createreference#1#2{\@bsphack
  \protected@write\@mainaux{}%
         {\string\newreference{#1}{#2}}%
  \@esphack}
```

This will lead to the aux files looking something like this:

```
\relax 
\newreference{john}{John Q. Citizen}
```

The `\@bsphack`/`\@esphack` fixes a space issue by removing superfluous spaces. Basically `\@bsphack` tests for a space in front of the macro it is in and `\@esphack` looks if there is a space following. If there are spaces on both sides one is removed resulting in only one space.

### 3. Test Macro

```
\AtEndDocument{%
    \def\newreference#1#2{%
    \edef\reserved@a{#2}%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname rfr@#1\endcsname\reserved@a%
    \else%
         \@tempswatrue%
    \fi}}
```

This overwrites the definition of `\newreference`. Before `\AtEndDocument` causes the aux file to be [read again](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213791/19326). It defines a macro `\reserved@a` to the new definition in the newly written auxfile and compares its definition to the definition create by the **Def Macro** during the initial read of the auxfile latex did at the start of the compile. There is an empty if branch, however if these values differ `\@tempswatrue` is executed causing Latex to issue a `Compile again` message at the end of its run.