# Purpose of AtEndDocument{\def}

Tags: hooks

I am currently researching how to generate a recompilation warning from Latex if somthing in the auxfile changes and found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49035/19326) solution.

However I find it rather confusing, it uses:

```
\AtEndDocument{\def\newreference#1#2{...}}
```

Which looks to me as if it simply redefines the macro `\newreference#1#2` (where `#1` and `#2` expand to the arguments given to the surrounding macro). However I do not know from where `\newreference#1#2` is "called" (expanded? used?) to actually do the check.

I tried taking a look at [clsguide](http://tex.loria.fr/general/new/clsguide.html#Sec:delays) and at the points when the [auxfile is read](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120973/when-is-the-aux-file-read-and-written). But neither was helpful (apparently the auxfile is only read at `\begin{document}` so this does not explain it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what `\enddocument` looks like in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx):

```
\def\enddocument{%
   \let\AtEndDocument\@firstofone
   \@enddocumenthook
   \@checkend{document}%
   \clearpage
   \begingroup
     \if@filesw
       \immediate\closeout\@mainaux
       \let\@setckpt\@gobbletwo
       \let\@newl@bel\@testdef
       \@tempswafalse
       \makeatletter \@@input\jobname.aux
     \fi
     \@dofilelist
     \ifdim \font@submax >\fontsubfuzz\relax
       \@font@warning{Size substitutions with differences\MessageBreak
                  up to \font@submax\space have occurred.\@gobbletwo}%
     \fi
     \@defaultsubs
     \@refundefined
     \if@filesw
       \ifx \@multiplelabels \relax
         \if@tempswa
           \@latex@warning@no@line{Label(s) may have changed.
               Rerun to get cross-references right}%
         \fi
       \else
         \@multiplelabels
       \fi
     \fi
   \endgroup
   \deadcycles\z@\@@end}
\def\@testdef #1#2#3{%
  \def\reserved@a{#3}\expandafter \ifx \csname #1@#2\endcsname
 \reserved@a  \else \@tempswatrue \fi}
```

If `@filesw` is true (you didn't make a call to `\nofiles`), then LaTeX closes the main `.aux` file (`\immediate\closeout\@mainaux`), but after some redefinitions, reads the main `.aux` again: `\makeatletter \@@input\jobname.aux`.

The redefinitions above is important in that it checks whether `\label`s match their definitions. [Boris' code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49035/5764) attempts to do the same by redefining `\newreference` in a similar way to how LaTeX redefines `\@newl@bel` (via `\let\@newl@bel\@testdef`).

Comment: While my latex knowledge is not sufficient enough to fully understand the details, your excellent awnser stating that the redefinitions are applied before the output file **is** read **again** clarified it a lot.

Comment: @ted: Yes. You can also look at the `.log` output, where you'll see references to the `.aux` being printed multiple times.

Answer (score 6):

Package `rerunfilecheck` calculates MD5 hashes (pdfTeX/LuaTeX in DVI or PDF mode)
of the auxiliary files and compares them at the very end of the document,
later than `\AtEndDocument`, where the `.aux` file is still open. See package
`atveryend` for later hooks.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[aux]{rerunfilecheck}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Hello}
\end{document}
```

First run:

```
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `test.aux' has changed. Rerun.
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `test.toc' has changed. Rerun.
```

Comment: I am sorry that my question is a bit unclear if you omit the title but I was rather interested in the mechanics of the commands quoted than an allternative. I think this answer would have fitted better to my original question that led me here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213683/19326). I referenced your awnser in a comment there